# Unexpected file format when trying to open a .fla file

Tags: flash, flash-cs3, adobe-flash-cs3

I am trying to customize a video player skin from f4player (http://code.google.com/p/f4player/downloads/detail?name=f4player-beta-v1.00.zip [the file is mySkin.fla]).

I am using flash cs3 pro and I get the error "Unexpected file format" when trying to open the file, a friend has flash cs4 and has the same error.

Is there something I could do to open this .fla file correctly?

Or maybe if someone could try opening it and saving it again for cs3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Flash CS5 document, so you need Flash CS5 (or 5.5) to edit it. You could download a trial version from adobe.com.

Comment: I thought to download this file and save it for you so you can open it but, I can only save for CS4. I also have CS4 but havnt installed it. If I did I could save as CS3 FLA but unfortunately I don't have time to do this. Just posted this so that you dont waste your time downloading CS5 and trying to save it for CS3, won't work can only save 1 version back in each IDE. Nice eh? Thanks Adobe!